# Redirect each flask request to same apache process

Tags: apache, flask, mod-wsgi

I am trying to run flask with apache. I am using mode_wsgi apache module for configuration. My file like this only.

```
<VirtualHost *>
    ServerName example.com
    WSGIDaemonProcess myapplication 
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/yourapplication/myapplication.wsgi
    <Directory /var/www/myapplication>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
   </Directory>
   </VirtualHost>
```

But when i am trying to access my application each request goes to new process id but i want to redirect all the request to same apache pid. please let me know what changes i need to make in configuration file.

Comment: You are missing ``WSGIProcessGroup myapplication``.

Comment: yes i mention this variable also but still the request is going to the new pid.

Comment: You do not mention that configuration directive in what you said you were using. Show your updated configuration if you claim to have now added it. Also run the test described in http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/checking-your-installation.html#embedded-or-daemon-mode to ensure you are correctly configuring things to run in daemon mode. You probably should also read http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/processes-and-threading.html so you understand more about the different modes of mod_wsgi.

Comment: Thank you for help !! Now its working fine!!